# Ext.js Date Format Locale

Tags: javascript, extjs

I put the format to be (M d, Y)
where I want it to be "Nov 20, 2013"
works great in English.

The problem is - when I use different locale on the page, it does direct translation and not change the format to a format that is used in that location, for example, when I use Chinese it just transalte the word November. and not change the structure of the date.

any suggestion what can I do to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're providing your own date format (e.g. for a date field) then this format will be used, no matter if it is appropriate for the current location or not.

Assuming you're using a locale file `ext-lang-*.js`, you can use the property [Ext.Date.defaultFormat](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Date-property-defaultFormat), which will contain the format code of that locale.

Alternatively, you can also set the value of that property yourself:

```
Ext.Date.defaultFormat = 'Y-m-d'; // your format here
```

**EDIT:** I just had a look the chinese language files and it seems that they do **not** set a defaultFormat, so you will have to set it yourself (as described above).

Comment: So I need to implicitly set different formans to different locales ah? It ain't happen automatically? OK then. setting the value of that property by myself is good enough. Do you know how can I change it in the locale file?

Comment: If you are using a locale file it actually should be done automatically. E.g. the German language file contains that line:`Ext.Date.defaultFormat = 'd.m.Y';`
Unfortunately this does not seem to be the case for all locale files (such as the Chinese one), so it's somehow inconsistent. Afaik those files are contributed by the community mostly, so probably that's the reason.
The locale files are located in `ext-dir/locale`.